# Rails 4: Form_for looks for wrong path after adding in password field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an organization model that has many members to it.

My routes look like this:

```
resources :organizations, except: [:destroy] do
  resources :departments, except: [:destroy, :index]
  resources :members
end
```

and my form for a new member looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([@organization, @member]) do |f| %>
```

now everything was working correctly (I was able to create members and it they were correctly associated with their organizations), but once I added password digest to the members migration, and `has_secure_password` to the members model, and `password_fields` in the view, it would give me a

```
undefined method `members_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f90b639d110>:0x007f90b3714f80>
```

I don't understand why it's not looking for `organization_members_path` anymore.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to specify

```
url: organization_members_path
```

within form_for. Why? I have no idea.